# Inverse matrix from text file using Gauss elimination. C++

Tags: c++, csv, matrix, gaussian, inverse

I need to write a program that reads in a matrix from a comma separated values file, and then uses Gaussian elimination to calculate the inverse and write this inverse out to a new file.

Reading it in is fine, as is writing it back out. I think I understand how Gaussian elimination works and am able to do this by using an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//  main program starts here
int main() {
//  create a vector of a vector to store original matrix
//  and matrices after each calculation
vector<vector<double>> data;
int n_com = 0;

//  try to read input file
ifstream readFile("test_data.txt");

if (readFile.is_open()){
    while (!readFile.eof()){
        int i;

        //  declare temporary line vector and line string
        vector<double> vline;
        string aLine;

        //  assign line of file to line string
        getline(readFile, aLine);

        //  count number of commas in line string
        n_com = count(aLine.begin(), aLine.end(), ',');

        //  define integer for start of each element
        int start = 0;

        //  loop over all but final element
        for (i=0; i < n_com; i++) {

            //  declare and find position of next comma
            int comma_pos;
            comma_pos = aLine.find(',', start);

            //  declare string for element and assign substring to it
            string elems;
            elems = aLine.substr(start, comma_pos - start);

            //  convert string to double
            double elemd = atof(elems.c_str());

            //  push back double to temporary vector
            vline.push_back(elemd);

            //  redefine start for next iteration
            start = comma_pos + 1;
        }
        //  assign final element to string
        string final_elems = aLine.substr(start, aLine.length() - start);

        //  convert final element to double and push back to vector
        double final_elemd = atof(final_elems.c_str());
        vline.push_back(final_elemd);

        //  push back line vector to data vector
        data.push_back(vline);
    }
}
else {
    //  print error if unable to open file
    printf("Error unable to open input file!\n");
    //  exit program
    exit(1);
}
//  close input file
readFile.close();
```

So this is how I've read in the original matrix.

This is the code I have for Gaussian elimination for an array

```
//  calculate width and length of original data (no. of rows and columns)
int length = data.size();
int width = n_com + 1;

//  create new file to write to
ofstream writeFile ("tranpose.txt");

//  check outfile is open
if (writeFile.is_open()){

    //  declare indices
    //  width (columns)
    int i;
    // length (rows)0
    int j;
    //  k
    int k;

    //  declare a float?
    float data[10][10] = {0},d;

    //  identity matrix
    for (i=1; i <= length; i++){
        for (j=1; j <= 2 * length; j++){
            if (j == (i + length)){
                data[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //  partial pivoting
    for (i=length; i > 1; i--){
        if (data[i-1][1] < data[i][1]){
            for(j=1;j <= length * 2; j++){
                d = data[i][j];
                data[i][j] = data[i-1][j];
                data[i-1][j] = d;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Augmented Matrix: "<<endl;
    for (i=1; i <= length; i++){
        for (j=1;j <= length * 2; j++){
            cout<<data[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    //  reducing to diagonal matrix
    for (i=1; i <= length; i++){
        for (j=1; j <= length * 2; j++){
            if (j != i){
                d = data[j][i] / data [i][i];
                for (k=1; k<= length * 2; k++){
                    data[j][k] = data[j][k] - (data[i][k] * d);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //  reducing to unit matrix
    for (i=1; i <= length; i++){
        d = data[i][i];
        for (j=1; j <= length * 2; j++){
            data[i][j] = data[i][j] / d;
        }
    }
    //  print inverse matrix in console
    cout<<"Inverse Matrix "<<endl;
    for (i=1; i <= length; i++){
        for (j = length + 1; j <= length * 2; j++){
            cout<<data[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    //  loop over all rows
    for (i=1; i <= length; i++){
        //  loop over all columns
        for (j = length + 1; j <= length * 2; j++){
            //  print data in transposed positions excluding last value
            //  i.e. [j][i] instead of [i][j]
            writeFile << setw(4) << fixed << setprecision(2) << data[i][j] << ",";
        }
        // print onto new line
        int i = length - 1;
        writeFile << setw(4) << fixed << setprecision(2) << data[i][j] << "\n";

    }

    //  close written file
    writeFile.close();
```

How can I write this so that it will use the data stored from my vector, or matrix file, instead of a normal array of numbers?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask. A vector of vectors behaves exactly like a 2D array in terms of element access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I thought too, but this code will just take a matrix of 0s as its input and then invert that, getting a matrix of "nan"s.

I would just like to know the problems in this code and how I can write a gauss elimination properly, applying it to my input text file.

Comment: Try commenting out this line `float data[10][10] = {0},d;`

Comment: Thank you, just tried this and build fails because I use "undeclared identifier d"

    //  partial pivoting
         for (i=length; i > 1; i--){
             if (data[i-1][1] < data[i][1]){
                 for(j=1;j <= length * 2; j++){
                     d = data[i][j];
                     data[i][j] = data[i-1][j];
                     data[i-1][j] = d;

Comment: Well, I mean comment out the redefinition of `data`, leave the `d` alone.

Comment: Not really sure how to do this? Sorry! But yes this is the problem, I need to get rid of this redefinition and somehow get it to work but I have tried removing it before and it will throw up "bad access" errors.

Comment: Just put them in different lines.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I am new to this, put what in different lines?

Comment: Just put `\\float data[10][10] = {0};` in one line to common it out, and then put `float d;` in another line.

Comment: Thanks. This results in the line data[i][j]=1 having the error "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)"

In fact, if I delete that line (and the identity matrix part of the code altogether), it then proceeds to have the same problem with the rest of the gauss elimination code. for example, where it has " if (data[i-1][1] < data[i][1]){"

Answer (score 1):

I refined the entire thing because your algorithm doesn't look right to me.

```
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

Matrix inverse(Matrix mat)
{
    // Use Gaussian elimination
    // Using two matrixs instead of one agumented
    // to improve peformance

    auto height = mat.size();
    auto width = mat[0].size();

    // Create an identity matrix
    Matrix result(height, Matrix::value_type(width));
    for (auto i = 0;i < width;++i) {
        result[i][i] = 1;
    }
    cout << "Augmented Matrix: " << endl;
    printTwo(mat, result);

    // reduce to Echelon form
    for (auto j = 0;j < width;++j) {
        // partial pivoting
        auto maxRow = j;
        for (auto i = j;i < height;++i) {
            maxRow = mat[i][j]>mat[maxRow][j] ? i : maxRow;
        }
        mat[j].swap(mat[maxRow]);
        result[j].swap(result[maxRow]);

        cout << "pivotted Matrix: " << endl;
        printTwo(mat, result);

        // Reduce row by row
        auto pivot = mat[j][j];
        auto& row1L = mat[j];
        auto& row1R = result[j];
        for (auto i = j + 1;i < height;++i) {
            auto& row2L = mat[i];
            auto& row2R = result[i];
            auto temp = row2L[j];
            for (auto k = 0;k < width;++k) {
                row2L[k] -= temp / pivot*row1L[k];
                row2R[k] -= temp / pivot*row1R[k];
            }
        }
        // Make diaganal elements to 1
        for (auto k = 0;k < width;++k) {
            row1L[k] /= pivot;
            row1R[k] /= pivot;
        }
        cout << "reduced Matrix: " << endl;
        printTwo(mat, result);
    }

    //back subsitution
    for (auto j = width - 1;;--j) {
        auto& row1L = mat[j];
        auto& row1R = result[j];
        for (auto i = 0;i < j;++i) {
            auto& row2L = mat[i];
            auto& row2R = result[i];
            auto temp = row2L[j];
            for (auto k = 0;k < width;++k) {
                row2L[k] -= temp*row1L[k];
                row2R[k] -= temp*row1R[k];
            }
        }
        cout << "subsituted Matrix: " << endl;
        printTwo(mat, result);
        if (j == 0) break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here's the helper used in the code:

```
void printTwo(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs)
{
    for (auto i = 0;i < lhs.size();++i) {
        for (auto elm : lhs[i]) {
            cout << setw(4) << elm << ' ';
        }

        for (auto elm : rhs[i]) {
            cout << setw(4) << elm << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```